# How to get my MDX query to work in an excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, mdx

I'm trying to get the below code to work in an excel cell, the plan would then be to change the Residence Country Grouping to different values for a spreadsheet i need to populate with different values coming from the cube. The MDX query works, just can't make it work in excel.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.x as SUM
(EXCEPT
  (
[Account].[Account Currency].CHILDREN,
{[GBP],[EUR],[USD],[CHF],[JPY]}
  ),
[Measures].[BalanceSheetTotal])

select Measures.x on 0
FROM LCR

WHERE 
(
[Customer].[Residence Country Grouping].&[OtherEUMembers],
[Account].[Asset Type].&[Liability],
[Data Date].[Quarter Offset].&[0],
[LCR Code].[Level1].&[RE.12]
)
```

Comment: Sorry but what is your expectation? That the MDX just natively works in Excel or that you can connect to SSAS and make the call to get the data using that MDX query?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want the MDX to work in a cell in excel that's connected to my cube in SSAS. So the business case is I'm having to fill in a business excel sheet with loads of figures coming from the cube. I have got most to work using CubeValues but can't work out how to get this MDX to work in excel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy paste from a Greg Galloway answer:

The CUBEVALUE function expects a member, not a formula that returns a number. So you need to create the calculated member in the cube or at least on the session. If you don't want to alter the definition of the cube and prefer the calculation lives in the Excel workbook's session with the cube, then do the following.

Install the free OLAP PivotTable Extensions.

Create a PivotTable somewhere in your workbook against that "SSAS" connection, right click on the PivotTable and choose OLAP PivotTable Extensions. Create a new calculated measure with name My Calc and formula:

```
SUM( {NULL:[Calender].[Day].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(8)}, [Measure].[x])
```

Then change your CUBEVALUE formula to:

```
=CUBEVALUE("SSAS","[Measures].[My Calc]")
```